# Is there a faster Average?

Tags: dax

Running this in DAX Studio shows me two queries that run one that sums up the Usage and I assume the other to count for the division needed to do the Average. . .

```
DEFINE
    MEASURE Usage[New KanBan Qty] =
        VAR CurrentDate =
            TODAY ()
        VAR ThreeMthSmoothed =
            CALCULATE (
                AVERAGEX ( Usage, Usage[Smoothed Usage] ),
                FILTER ( Usage, Usage[Usage Date] >= CurrentDate - 90 )
            ) * -1
        RETURN
            (
                ThreeMthSmoothed * MAX ( IMAG[JIT Leadtime] )
                    + (
                        ( STDEV.P ( Usage[Smoothed Usage] ) * [ServiceFactor] )
                            * SQRT ( MAX ( IMAG[JIT Leadtime] ) )
                    )
            )
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE ( Usage, Usage[Part Number] ),
    "Stuff", [New KanBan Qty]
)
```

[image: Dax Studio Server Timings]

Answer (score 1):

You are using an iterator `AVERAGEX` inside of your `CALCULATE`. This is likely to be significantly slower than replacing `AVERAGEX(Usage, Usage[Smoothed Usage])` with `AVERAGE(Usage[Smoothed Usage])`.

The reason is that using an iterator function like `SUMX`, `PRODUCTX`, `AVERAGEX`, `MAXX`, `CONCATENATEX`, `FILTER` etc. requires the table you're iterating over to be saved in memory.

You can also probably replace,

`FILTER ( Usage, Usage[Usage Date] >= CurrentDate - 90 )`

with the simple Boolean filter `Usage[Usage Date] >= CurrentDate - 90`. This isn't 100% equivalent but may likely work in this case.

The combined measure definition would be

```
DEFINE
    MEASURE Usage[New KanBan Qty] =
        VAR CurrentDate = TODAY ()
        VAR ThreeMthSmoothed =
            CALCULATE (
                AVERAGE ( Usage[Smoothed Usage] ),
                KEEPFILTERS ( Usage[Usage Date] >= CurrentDate - 90 )
            ) * -1
        ...
```

Comment: `KEEPFILTERS` preserves the semantic of `FILTER ( 'Table', <predicate> )`. I edited with a consolidated measure definition based on your suggestions and using `KEEPFILTERS`.